# Construct an object with a mapping of parameters scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to create an object from a `Map[String, Any]` where each pair is a (StringField -> Value) ?

For example,

```
case class Example(a: String, b: Int)  
val obj = new Example( Map('a' -> 'blah', 'b' -> 1) ) //?
val orMaybe = Example( Map('a' -> 'blah', 'b' -> 1 ) //?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in several ways. One of them would be to use reflection, another (a simpler one) would be to use json as an intermediate.

E.g. with json4s:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}

scala> implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@1f2bf363

case class Example(a: String, b: Int)  
scala> val obj = read[Example](write( Map("a" -> "blah", "b" -> 1) ))
obj: Example = Example(blah,1)
scala: val orMaybe = read[Example](write( Map("a" -> "blah", "b" -> 1 )))
orMaybe: Example = Example(blah,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a tuple as the parameter list to a function using `.tupled`:

`(Example.apply _).tupled("a" -> 1)`

With that, and knowing that `myMap.map` passes each element of the Map as a `Tuple`, you could do the following:

`Map("a" -> 1).map((Example.apply _).tupled).head`